# mongoose-simpledb Loading an Array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose

I've been using [mongoose-simpledb](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongoose-simpledb) to write my app simply because it's what was used in a Tutorial I took when I was trying to learn all this stuff.  I'm stuck on trying to load an array in my schema and could really use some help!

The general idea is that I'm creating an entry in my database when a player creates a new game.  The game contains information about the game and then an array of teams that are associated with that game.  (Teams are exclusive to the game they are created in).

Here is my "Games" Schema:

```
exports.schema = {
    gameName: String,
    teams: [{
        userID: String,
        userName: String,
        points: Number
    }]
};

exports.methods = {

    AddTeam: function (db, newUserName) {

        //Make sure this user is an existing user
        db.User.findOne({ 'userName': newUserName }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) return console.error(err);

            //If a user gets returned then load his data into the game's teams array
            if (user) {
                this.teams.push({ 
                    userID: user.id,
                    userName: user.userName,
                    points: 0
                });
            } else {
                console.error("User Not Found");
            }
        });
    }
};
```

In my main post event I have a "for loop" that loads the userNames from the JSON request.

```
//Create a new game
var game = db.Games();

//load the game name
game.gameName = req.body.GameInfo.gameName;

//Create an invite list array
var inviteList = req.body.InviteList;

//Initialize the teams array
game.teams = [];

//Laod the teams array
for (i = 0; i < inviteList.length; i++) {
    console.log("This is what I'm loading into the teams array: " + inviteList[i]);
    game.AddTeam(db, inviteList[i]);
}

//Save the Game object in the database
game.save();
```

The error I'm getting from my Node.js serve is:

```
    /home/jeff/nodejs/testSite/dbmodels/Games.js:18
                this.teams.push({
                           ^
    TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
        at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/jeff/nodejs/testSite/dbmodels/Games.js:18:28)
```

"Line 18" that is is referring to is this line:
    this.teams.push({

It seems the issue with using something like simpledb is that if you hit a roadblock you can't simply go look at straight mongoose examples.

Answer (score 1):

I think thats because you use this.teams in context of callback

try write this before db.User.findOne:
var teams = this.teams

and in callback use it:
teams.push(...);